# contiguous_iterator c++20 как это работает

Tags: c++, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++, c++20

Я в упор не понимаю что тут происходит, Можете вкратце объяснить как это использовать например для пользовательского шаблонного класса строк где есть строки ***char** или ***wchar_t** и **leng_str**. Благодарю за ответы.

```
template<class I>
    concept contiguous_iterator =
        random_access_iterator<I> &&
        derived_from<ITER_CONCEPT(I), contiguous_iterator_tag> &&
        is_lvalue_reference_v<iter_reference_t<I>> &&
        same_as<iter_value_t<I>, remove_cvref_t<iter_reference_t<I>>> &&
        requires(const I& i) {
            { to_address(i) } -> same_as<add_pointer_t<iter_reference_t<I>>>;
        };
```

Comment: `concept` проверяет тип на соответствие определенным критерям. Залезайте в самый глубокий концепт (в `random_access_iterator` и дальше до `input_or_output_iterator` -> `weakly_incrementable` и т.д.), и реализуйте оттуда все требования подряд в своем классе итератора. Через `static_assert(...)` проверяйте свой класс на соответствие.

Comment: Есть еще второй набор требований, которые cppreference называет [LegacyIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) и т.п. Это - старые требования, которые были в ходу до концептов из С++20 (и где-то в стандарте до сих пор используются). Они почти эквивалентны, но их намного проще читать.

Comment: Но вообще, вы же можете просто указатели использовать вместо итераторов. Они подходят подо все эти требования. Только проверку границ вы в них сделать не сможете.

Comment: Ну, я же написал. Возвращайте указатели из begin и end. Если хотите проверку границ в итераторах, то пишите свои классы по требованиям выше.